# Can sizeof be used with class names in C++?

Tags: c++

Here's a sample class below:

```
class abc {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

Using `sizeof` in the code below, will it give the size of the class? Why?

```
int c = sizeof(abc);
```

Comment: Yes. Why didn't you try this yourself?

Comment: In C++ you should rarely need to find out the size of your class in this way.

Comment: Classes aren't objects, so they don't have a size. `sizeof(abc)` tells you the size of an instance of class `abc`.

Comment: Don't forget that you need a semicolon to close the class declaration.

Comment: @Casey Classes *are* objects. The standard says an object is anything that takes up memory. Instances of a class do take up memory -- just like instances of int take memory so they're both objects.

Comment: @Rapptz Classes do not take up memory. *Instances* of classes take up memory. Therefore *Instances* are objects, but *Classes* are not objects.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf new abc

Comment: In C++ you should do everything you can to avoid allocating memory for a class manually.  The new operator is the way to go.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf I don't see any "sizeof" in your code so I don't understand why it is relevent. What you are doing looks quite advanced anyway. I said "rarely", not "never".

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf I have no idea what you are talking about. I code C++ with new, smart pointers and STL. I very rarely use sizeof. I'm not saying it isn't used under the hood or that it may be required by advanced techniques, but if a beginner C++ programmer is using sizeof on his classes he is probably making a mistake.

Comment: Due to the ample opportunities to stumble into undefined behaviour, try it yourself can be risky advice in C++.

Comment: To help eliminate some confusion, [here's a better definition for "object" with respect to C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object).

Answer (score 5):

That will work.  In fact, that's the entire purpose of the [sizeof operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) when used in that way.

Using `sizeof(type)`:

> returns size in bytes of the object representation of type.

In your case, the class name is the type.